# Error in ruby: cannot load such file -- zlib

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

When I try to install rails in Ubuntu 12.10 I get this error:

```
$ gem install rails
ERROR: Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR: While executing gem ... (NameError)
uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

So I completely removed rvm:

```
rvm implode
sudo rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

removed the script calls in my `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`

and checked if they're really removed:

```
env | grep rvm #no output, so rvm is removed
ruby -v #The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages: blabla
```

I already have these via sudo apt-get install:

```
curl zlib1g-dev zlib1g libssl-dev build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config
```

Then proceed to install from scratch

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --auto-dotfiles
```

then run that line and restarted terminal regard to this message:

```
  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /home/adige/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.
```

Then `rvm pkg install readline` but completed with error:

```
...
Error running 'autoreconf -is --force', please read /home/adige/.rvm/log/readline/autoreconf.log
...
Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force
```

I think it's installed anyway, right? Before reinstall all rubies, I installed zlib of course:

```
# w/out verify, it gives checksum error
rvm pkg install zlib --verify-downloads 1
```

Then run `rvm reinstall all --force` and completed with error again:

```
...
Install of ruby-1.9.3-p374 - #complete 
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p374 pristine.
Error running '' under ,
please read /home/adige/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gemset.pristine.log
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p374@global pristine.
```

[gemset.pristine.log](http://pastebin.com/ZrmWStNB)

Then reinstall ruby with zlib support:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p374 --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

which returned same error and [same log](http://pastebin.com/ZrmWStNB) but completed anyway.

Finally I tried to install rails gem again but `cannot load such file -- zlib` !

Here is the [rvm info](http://pastebin.com/08fp9PVW)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not install `readline` / `zlib` on ubuntu, follow this steps:

```
rvm get head
rvm pkg remove
rvm requirements run force
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p374
```

make sure to include output of the installation process if this fails, also include all mentioned log files